# Map in react component not able to call map.get()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hashmap

I have a simple error message Map that is getting populated correctly. Here's 
a code snippet from the validate function.

```
function validate(firstName, lastName, email) {

    var errors = new Map();

    if (firstName == null || firstName.length === 0) {
      errors.set(1, "First Name can't be empty");
    }
    if (lastName == null || lastName.length === 0) {
        errors.set(2, "Last Name can't be empty");
.
.
.
```

In my component, errors var is populated by the validate function.
`var errors = validate(firstName, lastName, email)`

When I leave the first name blank in my app, I should get a map with one 
value set and I do.`console.log(errors)` yields this in console

[image: Console output for errors]

So I know I have a valid map. How do I get the value from key 1?

Errors.get(1) is not working.

`console.log(error.get(1)` keeps giving me this

[image: TypeError stack]

Not sure where to go from here since all documentation says the 
the get() is how to retrieve the values I want.

After further investigation, other than the errors.set() calls I make in the 
validate function, I cant call any map functions on the errors map from within
the render() function of the component

Comment: The problem is not evident from the info you've provided. Are you calling both `console.log(errors)` and `console.log(errors.get(1))` in the same context (in the same function, using the same `errors` object) ?

Comment: Im actually replacing ```console.log(errors)``` with ```console.log(errors.get(1))```
it is the same error var each time.  Outputting just errors gives the map info in console, outputting errors.get breaks with a TypeError.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: In the error message you seem to get the `errors` object from the state (`var errors = this.state`) inside the `render` function, this function is called multiple times, it is possible that `errors` is not a `Map` every time this function is called.

Comment: Can you update question with where you have set the state with errors map?

Comment: What error you are getting in console?